# Sign-out Styling in adminlte using asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, bootstrap-4

Im using the rather excellent [admintlte](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/layout/top-nav.html) for my dashboard however I am having a slight issue with the styling of the logout as it must be a form in asp.net core mvc.

Any ideas how one would use anchor tag normal a tag I tried using asp-controller but it didnt sign me out properly it just bought me to my home page.

It should look more like the setup link without the button affect around it.

I am using the following code at the present

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
   <a asp-action="Setup" asp-controller="Admin" asp-route-id="1" class="dropdown-item">
        <i class="fas fa-user mr-2"></i> Setups</a>
  
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>


    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">

    
            <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm">
                <i class="fas fa fa-sign-in-alt mr-2"></i>
                <button type="submit" class="nav-link">Sign out</button>
            </form>
            </a>
    } else {
        <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer fa fa-sign-in-alt">Login</a>
        <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">Register</a>

    }

</div>
```

Currently it is looking like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You put the form as hidden, and execute JavaScript on the anchor tag to simulate the form submit.

```
<form class="d-none" method="post" id="logoutForm
  asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout"">
</form>
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('#logoutForm').submit()" 
  class="dropdown-item">
    <i class="fas fa fa-sign-in-alt mr-2"></i>
    Sign Out
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks budy that worked a treat. Admintlte is a great them have used it a few times just that one i keep foregeting about.

Comment: Yep I usually craft out my own theme on my .NET Core projects, and this snippet is handy.

Comment: I keep  meaning to build up and use my snippets but that i never get round to probally one the features i underuse its their fear of loosing it all when re isntall

Comment: Its still not inline its a we bit to close to the edge some reason

Comment: Sorry I typed `dropdown-menu-item` instead of `dropdown-item`. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I actually came up with a different approach I used

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">


        <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm">
            <i class="fas fa fa-sign-in-alt mr-2"></i>
            <button type="submit"  class="link">Sign out</button>
        </form>
    </a>

  } else {
    <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer fa fa-sign-in-alt">Login</a>
    <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">Register</a>

 }

</div>
```

Then in my css i just have the following

```
button.link {
 background: none !important;
 border: none;
 padding: 0 !important;
 /*optional*/
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
 /*input has OS specific font-family*/
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```